# iMac 27-inch late 2015 upgrade RAM with higher frequency

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory

My current RAM memory has 1867Mhz and I want to upgrade with 2133Mhz.

Can this cause any problems?

The RAM is compatible with my iMac, at least the manufacturer says so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mix 2133 with 1866 it will all run at 1866.

1. Replace all memory sticks with DDR3 2133MHz
2. Use quality components (Crucial, Kingston) or you may encounter freezing issues

Comment: So it doesn't affect at all some components of the machine or the system perfomance?

Comment: And what if the memory which I want to add has lower frequency more exactly 1600MHz? It does affect with something?